# Qt Form causing crash

Tags: c++, qt

I'm designing a form using the form editor in the following installation;

Qt Creator 3.2.1 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.3.2 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

EDIT: that info is from the 'About' window in Qt Creator, but it seems to be incorrect. The installer I used is qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013-5.3.2.

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0.

I've been able to start creating a form which will compile and run, but after a while of adding widgets and frames, the project starts to crash on start-up, with the following error message.

```
The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception.
Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception at 0×66aa00a7, code: 0xc0000005: read access
  violation at: 0×0, flags=0×0 (first chance).
```

The code in the project is absolutely minimal, I’ll paste it here:

```
Main::Main(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
{ ui->setupUi(this);
}

Main::~Main()
{ delete ui;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ QApplication a(argc, argv);

Main main; main.show(); a.exec(); }
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing the crash? The call-stack shows it's not happening anywhere near my code:

```
0 isRecursive qmutex.cpp 70 0×66aa00a7    
1 QBasicMutex::isRecursive qmutex.cpp 289 0×66a9f5b5
2 QBasicMutex::lockInternal qmutex.cpp 424 0×66a9f5f1 
3 QBasicMutex::lockInternal qmutex.cpp 417 0×66a9f5d1
```

I thought form-editors allowed you to design GUIS without worrying about this kind of thing.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Make sure you are using Qt binaries for the version of Visual Studio that you are using. It is not safe to use binaries from a different version of Visual Studio.

Comment: `ui->setupUi(this)` call is illegal, because `ui` member is not initialized.